# escape file and directory names from find

Tags: linux, bash, find

How can I escape spaces and other symbols from the results of a `find` command? For example, this doesn't work if there are spaces and other symbols in the results:

```
find -maxdepth 5 -type d -print | xargs du -sk | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `-print0` and `-0` options are not part of the POSIX specification, so this doesn't work if you need your script to work on multiple platforms (Linux, BSD, macOS).